# How to detect hoveron button? c# devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have 3 simple buttons from DevExpress. And I need no effects on hover. I was try to off it by ApperanceHovered but it's don't work.
[image]

I need to remove this blue hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you simply can apply these changes to your button easily using these two lines of codes.

Set the button's FlatStyle to Flat

```
this.btnClose.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Set the button's MouseOverBackColor to Transparent

```
this.btnClose.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Hope this will help. Thanks